# Tkinter does not receive string of IP properly

Tags: python, sockets, tkinter, ip

I have a problem with the `Entry` object of tkinter. basically, what I'm trying to do is receive an IP string from the user and first check if it null, then if is a valid ip address and then try to connect the client to the server socket. However...it seems as if the `Entry` just doesn't know when the `Entry`'s empty or how to check if the ip address is valid.

Code:

```
self.IPdst = StringVar()
txt_IP = Entry(Login_frame, bd=5, textvariable = self.IPdst,
               font = ('Arial', 14)).grid(row =1, column = 1, padx =20)

def is_ipv4(self):
    try:
        socket.inet_aton(self.IPdst)
        return True
    except socket.error:
        return False

def TryToConnectIP(self):
    if self.IPdst == '': #meaning empty
        messagebox.showerror('Error', 'filling field is required.')
    if self.is_ipv4() == True: #if ip address is valid computer will try to connect.
        pass
    else:
        messagebox.showerror('Error', 'Invalid IP address, please try again.')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter: AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute <attribute name>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name)

Comment: you need to call `self.IPdst.get()`

Comment: Hi Atlas435, it worked now =D, I realized I also did a real oopsie and confused the username variable with the IP variable in the entries... whoops. But definitely that helped me solve my previous problem. So thank you!